# Is there any alternative to webview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to integrate oauth verification such as google and facebook signin with rest api. I figured out webview is not really secure for oauth, can anyone suggest alternative to it or the way to make webview secure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser with deep link .Follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNxm_HcNcoo&ab_channel=MajidHajian)